# Почему невозможно вставить или обновить значение столбца mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, база-данных, .net

Здравствуйте!
Имеется таблица и в ней существует столбец, тип которого enum из-за него возникают все проблемы.
Использую следующий метод для выполнения необходимых манипуляций с записями таблицы (вставка / обновление).

```
public void AddParametersString(MySqlCommand command, string[] variables,  MySqlDbType[] mySqlDbTypes, string[] values)
    {
        int  i = 0, j=0;
        foreach (string val in values)
            command.Parameters.Add(variables[i++], mySqlDbTypes[j++]).Value = val;                
    }
```

Когда пытаюсь добавить или изменить запись то возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Data truncated for column 'department' at row 1
```

Этот столбец имеет тип enum значения которого:

`ENUM('Хлебо-булочный', 'Молочный', 'Колбасный', 'Мясной', 'Рыбный', 'Кондитерский', 'Овощной', 'Фруктовый', 'Кулинария', 'Полуфабрикаты', 'Вино-водочный', 'Бакалея')`

Почему так происходит?
Как решить данную проблему?
Спасибо заранее!)

Comment: Вероятно, размера столбца не хватило.

Comment: Размер столбца в самой таблице MySql?!
В столбце 'department' datatype стоит значение ENUM()

Comment: Он прямо в базе ENUM? Скорее всего нет, просто эмуляция в ORM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Размер

Если это поле в базе типа `VARCHAR`, вам необходимо увеличить длину этого поля чтобы хватало для всех возможных значений эмулированного в ORM `Enum`.
Обычно длина также указывается в аннотациях к полю модели.

#### Тип

Такая же ошибка может возникнуть, когда вы передаёте значение `NULL` в не-`nullable` поле. Добавьте полю флаг nullable, либо проверяйте в коде на null и бросайте соответствующее исключение/обрабатывайте этот случай.

#### Значение

Убедитесь, что передаваемые значения присутствуют в наборе ENUM поля данных. Вы используете русскоязычные значения, так-что, помимо прочего, проверьте кодировки.

Comment: Передаваемые значения присутствуют. Они были изъяты из самого набора ENUM поля данных при вставке или обновлении. 
Кодировки также проверены `utf-8`
Тип поля ENUM()
Насчёт типов, то всё впорядке: `department enum('Хлебо-булочный','Молочный','Колбасный','Мясной','Рыбный','Кондитерский','Овощной','Фруктовый','Кулинария','Полуфабрикаты','Вино-водочный','Бакалея') DEFAULT NULL,` Что тогда может быть?

Comment: Ещё может передаваться пустая строка... Вы выяснили, с каким конкретно значением происходит ошибка?

Comment: Всё уже выяснилось. Спасибо. Моя вина была.

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за помощь. Много чего сегодня полезного за ENUM узнал.